# How to make a YouTube full screen stretch over two monitors?

Tags: youtube, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome.
I tried HTML5, pepper flash, and normal flash but I always see the video on one monitor.

I tried `http://www.youtube.com/v/[video-id]` but I see the Chrome tabs and bars.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: While not strictly off-topic here, I think perhaps this question would do better on [su].

Comment: @AlE. I tend to agree, but I think as stated, it looks like a YouTube concern and would likely get bounced back.

Answer (score 1):

So long as your OS sees your monitors as two, distinct screens I don't think a browser plugin will be able to (effectively) split the video and project the separate halves on separate screens in sync.

What OS and video card are you using? Display adapters like the [Matrox DualHead2Go Digital](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital/) or the [AMD Eyefinity](http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/eyefinity) will create a single display from your multiple screens. Then, when your video goes full screen, it will spread out across multiple monitors as you intend.

The adapter needs to be comparable with the graphics card, so you'd have a bit of homework to do.

Comment: I'm not sure how special video drivers or hardware can be needed.  I use the OP's method in Edge and it works fine.  I'm looking for the same answer because I'd like to use Chrome but nobody seems to know how to make it work.  Google owns youtube!  How can Edge play it better than Chrome?